# Jstree get check box selected from the ids from database

Tags: jquery, jstree

I had created a jstree from json data

```
$('#tree-container').jstree({
    'core': {
        'data': {
            'url': 'permission.php',
            'data': function(node) {
                return {'id': node.id};
            },
            "dataType": "json"
        },
        'themes': {
            'responsive': true,
            'icons': true
        },
        'checkbox': {
            "keep_selected_style": false
        }
    },                
    'plugins': ['state', 'contextmenu','checkbox']
});
```

How to make the check box selected from the values i will get from database using an ajax and json?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the tree to start out with checkboxes selected based on your JSON data, or that you want to build the tree then have an Ajax call return JSON and automatically check boxes for you?

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple and easy to implement way of showing checkbox "checked" on jstree load(as per user selection stored in database).

```
Front end code:
```

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ajaxResponse = '';
    $.ajax({
     url  : 'response.php',
     async  : false,
     success : function(response)
     {
      ajaxResponse = response;
     }
    });
    var tree = $("#container");
    tree.html(ajaxResponse);
    tree.jstree({
        plugins: ["checkbox" ], //["wholerow", "checkbox", "json_data", "ui", "themes"]
        'checkbox': {
            three_state: false,
            cascade: 'up'
        }
    });
    tree.jstree(true).open_all();
    $('li[data-checkstate="checked"]').each(function() {
        tree.jstree('check_node', $(this));
    });
    tree.jstree(true).close_all();
});
</script>
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JsTree test</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jstree.com/latest/assets/dist/themes/default/style.min.css" />
    <script src="http://static.jstree.com/latest/assets/dist/libs/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://static.jstree.com/latest/assets/dist/jstree.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"/>
</body>
</html>
```

```
$getParentNodes = "select id, name from permissions where inherit_id IS NULL";
$resParentNodes = mysqli_query($conn, $getParentNodes);

$response = '';
if(mysqli_num_rows($resParentNodes) > 0)
{
    while($parentNode = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resParentNodes))
    {
        $response .= '<ul><li data-checkstate="unchecked">'.$parentNode['name'];

        $getChildNodes = "select id, name from permissions where inherit_id = '".$parentNode['id']."'";
        $resChildNodes = mysqli_query($conn, $getChildNodes);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($resChildNodes) > 0)
        {
            $response .= '<ul>';
            while($childNode = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resChildNodes))
            {
                $checked = 'data-checkstate="unchecked"';
                if($childNode['id'] == 5 || $childNode['id'] == 10 || $childNode['id'] == 11)
                {
                    $checked = 'data-checkstate="checked"';
                }
                $response .= '<li '.$checked.'>'.$childNode['name'].'</li>';
            }
            $response .= '</ul>';
        }

        $response .= '</li></ul>';
    }
}

echo $response;

This will show the checkbox checked with "data-checkstate="checked"
```